# how to handle onChange when new input component is added with a button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form where users can press a button to add more input fields below the one created. The purpose is adding different product sizes and the price of each depending on that specific product.

When add button is pressed, 2 text inputs next to each other get added, 1 for the size eg. Small and the 2nd for the price 100$.

How do i store the values in state when more boxes are rendered?

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            boxtext:'',
            addBox:[],
            fields:[],
            counter:0,
        };
    }

 addTextBox = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const boxAdded = [...this.state.addBox]
            boxAdded.push(1)
            this.setState({
                addBox: boxAdded
            })
            this.setState({counter:this.state.counter + 1})
        }


  handleChange = () => {
            let fields = { ...this.state.boxtext };
            fields = fields + "+";
            this.setState({ fields });
        };

    onAdd = async(e) => {
        const {addBox,boxtext,fields,counter} = this.state;

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(addBox,fields,counter,boxtext)
    };

render() {

rerturn(
<button style={{marginLeft:20,width:60,height:60,backgroundColor:'white',borderRadius:30,color:'dodgerblue',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',borderWidth:2,borderColor:'dodgerblue'}} onClick={this.addTextBox}>
    <span style={{fontSize:32,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',flex:1}}>
        +
        </span>
        </button>
{
    this.state.addBox.map(()=>{
        return(
            <div className="flex flex-nowrap w-full">
            <input
                type="text"
                className='form-control'
                id="exampleInputLogic"
                aria-describedby="logicHelp"
                placeholder="enter size"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                className='form-control'
                id="exampleInputLogic"
                aria-describedby="logicHelp"
                placeholder="enter price"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            </div>
        )  
    })
}

<span onClick={this.onAdd}
>
Add              
</span>
)
}
```

Nothing from the text inputs get dispalyed in the console.log in the onAdd function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use addBox as a array to collect all the data in the input box, then render by the addBox

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class AddBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      boxtext: "",
      addBox: [],
      fields: "",
      counter: 0
    };
  }

  initBoxItem = {
    size: 10,
    price: 4
  };

  addTextBox = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const boxAdded = [...this.state.addBox];
    boxAdded.push(this.initBoxItem);
    this.setState({
      addBox: boxAdded
    });
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const [type, index] = e.target.name.split("@");
    const currentAddBox = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.addBox));
    const currentBox = currentAddBox[+index];
    if (currentBox) {
      currentBox[type] = +e.target.value;
      this.setState({ addBox: currentAddBox });
    }
  };
  onAdd = async (e) => {
    const { addBox, boxtext, fields, counter } = this.state;

    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(addBox, fields, counter, boxtext);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button
          style={{
            marginLeft: 20,
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
            backgroundColor: "white",
            borderRadius: 30,
            color: "dodgerblue",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: "dodgerblue"
          }}
          onClick={(e) => this.addTextBox(e)}
        >
          <span
            style={{
              fontSize: 32,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              flex: 1
            }}
          >
            +
          </span>
        </button>
        {this.state.addBox.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="flex flex-nowrap w-full" key={index}>
              <input
                name={`size@${index}`}
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputLogic"
                aria-describedby="logicHelp"
                placeholder="enter size"
                value={item.size}
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
              />
              <input
                name={`price@${index}`}
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputLogic"
                value={item.price}
                aria-describedby="logicHelp"
                placeholder="enter price"
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}

        <span onClick={this.onAdd}>Add</span>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[a small demo for you problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-kate-hfgmew?file=/src/Addbox.tsx:0-2632)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution but do you mind changing it to javascript instead of typesript

Comment: Also, even in the example provided i am not able to change the values inside the text input

Comment: Hi, sorry but i do not understand your recent comments

Comment: @kd12345 I have remove the Typescript type annotation and you can try this demo,  check it whether it meet your demand;[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-field-vil39e?file=/src/Addbox.js)

Comment: Hi, the text input is ONLY accepting numbers and not text, why is that?

Comment: Because this line `currentBox[type] = +e.target.value;`, you delete the plus sign,it will work well